# Call input value in controller from view angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my index.html page

```
<div class=" property_value col-md-1" style="width: 13%; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 2px">
  <h6>Property Value(RM)</h6>
  <input id="property_value" name="property_value" type="text" placeholder="500000" value="500000" ng-model="loanfilter.property_value" class="form-control property-value-input" style="height: 20px" />
</div>
```

And in my index.js controller file i have this function that should call the value of property

```
 $scope.paramsData = function() {
         params = {
           landType: $scope.loanfilter.land_type,
         property: '$scope.loanfilter.property_type,   
       };
       return param;
 };
```

But it doesnt seem to be working. How can i call this value from the view to controller in angularjs.

Thanks

Comment: why do you have `'$scope.loanfilter.property_type, ` between `'` ?

Comment: In your view your referencing loanfilter.property_value but in the js object your referencing loanfilter.property_type, they need to be one in the same. Additionally, there's no need for that ' you have after property: and before $scope. Also your return, your declaring the object params but telling it to return param, again two different variables.

Comment: @ThatTechGuy nice catch on the comments but that wasnt the problem. The main problem was i needed to add a name to my form and then call d value of each input based on their name and value so formName.inputTypeName.value.

Comment: @KingsleySimon You certainly don't have to do that. You can call any value from any input binded to a model simply by its variable, regardless of whether or not it is even in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to declare `loanfilter` and `loanfilter.property_value` in your `$scope` near the top of your controller. That way, binding should be happening.

```
$scope.loanfilter = {};
$scope.loanfilter.property_value = '';
```

Hope that helps.